# Kernel Unexpectedly Quits in evaluating NExpectation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, crash

I have defined a function (EVR) that is the expectation of a term with an integral inside. I'm trying the expression when using a uniform distribution with min = 0 and max = 2*b (a random parameter). The formula j[x,b] is a condensed reference to the CDF of a uniform distribution.

```
EVR[n_, r_, c_, t_, R_, b_, LB_, UB_] := 
 NExpectation[
  a + t*Log[(1/c*
        Integrate[
         Exp[(x - a)/t]*(Sum[
            R*(Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]*
               h[x, b]*((n - 
                    k)*(j[x, b])^(n - k - 1)*(1 - j[x, b])^(k - 
                    1) - (k - 
                    1)*(j[x, b])^(n - k)*(1 - j[x, b])^(k - 2))), {k, 
             1, Floor[n*r], 1}]), {x, LB, a}, 
         Assumptions -> LB <= a <= UB, 
         GenerateConditions -> False]) + 1], 
  a \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*b}], PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
  Method -> {"NIntegrate", MaxRecursion -> 25}]
```

In general, this formula will execute fine for a single iteration (between 5 to 15 seconds to compute). I'm trying to run this expression inside a while loop and it usually causes the kernel to crash within the first 10 runs inside the While loop. I've tried many iterations but it continues to crash the kernel.

Comment: Can you please format the post for readability and use code blocks? As you can see, the code is not valid, as displayed.

Comment: Please provide the code for the definitions of the functions `h` and `j`

Comment: `h` is a simplified code for the pdf of a Uniform Distribution and `j` is the cdf of the Uniform

Comment: Would you give an example set of values you give `EVR`?  And please put in the code for `h` and `j` as requested previously.

Comment: Ranges of values: n - [5,25], r - (0,1), c - (.1,2], t - (.1,2], R - [1.10], b - [1,10], LB = 0, UB = 2*b. `h[x_, b_] := PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 2*b}], x]` and `j[x_, b_] := CDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 2*b}], x]`

Comment: I was able to correct the error by using `NIntegrate` and the definition of expectation to resolve the issue. Thanks to all who took a look.